# sort Javascript Array when Elements have no Title

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

```js
[["12/10/18", "00:30"],["12/17/18", "00:30"],["12/06/18", "00:30"],["12/11/18", "00:30"],["12/26/18", "00:45"],["12/22/18", "00:30"],
["12/25/18", "00:00"],["12/23/18", "00:30"],["12/28/18", "00:30"]]
```

i have an Array with variable length without title at front of the elements. How i could sort this Array after Date with Javascript for any length from array?

Comment: on what basis you want to sort the array ?

Comment: on the first position is everytime the Date and the array could look like [["12/10/18","otherelement","...",],["12/5/18","otherelement","...",],["23/10/18","otherelement","...",],[....] ]and i want that e.g. the ["12/5/18","otherelement","...",] on the first position and [["12/10/18","otherelement","...",] and the second and so on

Comment: The `Array.sort` callback expects two arguments. If you use `function(a, b)` you can simply compare `a[0]` and `b[0]`. Your question title suggests that the elements having no "title" (key) is an issue, but it isn't an issue at all. Arrays don't have keys, period. With keys you'd have an object. Sorting an array is trivial, simpler than sorting an Object with keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). This also sorts with the time, but can be removed if it's not required.

```js
const data = [["12/10/18", "00:30"],["12/17/18", "00:30"],["12/06/18", "00:30"],["12/11/18", "00:30"],["12/26/18", "00:45"],["12/22/18", "00:30"],["12/25/18", "00:00"],["12/23/18", "00:30"],["12/28/18", "00:30"]];

function toDate(a){
  const da1 = a[0].split("/").reverse();
  const ta1 = a[1].split(":");
  return Date.UTC(da1[0], da1[2]-1, da1[1], ...ta1);
}

const res = data.sort((a,b)=>{
  const d1 = toDate(a);
  const d2 = toDate(b);
  return d1 - d2;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why *reverse*? But otherwise, yes. You can just concatenate the values in yymmddhhmmss order and compare lexically, no need for a Date. :-) BTW, the years will all be treated as 20th century, which doesn't matter until some real 20th century years occur, like `12/31/99`.

Comment: @RobG ah well, in this scenario I don't really need it. It's true. Just a habit since I usually work with non US date formats dd/mm/yyyy. :P

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a nested array, you need to access the first element of each array in the list.

For example here, I am using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to sort the array in `dates`:

```
const moment = require('moment')
const dates = [["12/10/18", "00:30"],["12/17/18", "00:30"],["12/06/18", "00:30"],["12/11/18", "00:30"],["12/26/18", "00:45"],["12/22/18", "00:30"],["12/25/18", "00:00"],["12/23/18", "00:30"],["12/28/18", "00:30"]]

const sorted = dates.sort((a,b) =>
  moment(a[0], "MM/DD/YY") - moment(b[0], "MM/DD/YY")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest javascript way (No library required):

```js
   

let array = [["12/10/18", "00:30"],["12/17/18", "00:30"],["12/06/18", "00:30"],["12/11/18", "00:30"],["12/26/18", "00:45"],["12/22/18", "00:30"],
["12/25/18", "00:00"],["12/23/18", "00:30"],["12/28/18", "00:30"]];

let sortedArray = array.sort(function compare(a, b) {
  let dateA = new Date(a[0]);
  let dateB = new Date(b[0]);
  return dateA - dateB;
});

console.log('sorted array is : ',sortedArray);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to sort by date, you can use localeCompare to achieve that:

```
const temp = [["12/10/18", "00:30"],["12/17/18", "00:30"],["12/06/18", "00:30"],["12/11/18", "00:30"],["12/26/18", "00:45"],["12/22/18", "00:30"],
["12/25/18", "00:00"],["12/23/18", "00:30"],["12/28/18", "00:30"]]
let sorted = temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0])
})
```

If you want to sort the array in the opposite direction, use the reverse method or  `b[0].localeCompare(a[0])`

Comment: How on earth can this be the accepted answer? This does not compare dates but checks for lexicographically greaterness. Have fun next year in 01/01/2019...

Comment: @B12Toaster that made me giggle. Thanks for the laugh.

Comment: @B12Toaster—in the spirit of SO, the person who asked the question is allowed to  "accept" any answer they wish. However, they are often ill–equiped to determine the **best** answer. :-)